# Read qdebug within a test case?

Tags: c++, qt, qdebug

In my test case, I want to assert that the output of qDebug() includes a certain string. For example, this is what my test looks like. Notice the "Bound to UDP port 34772" output from qdebug. Can I test that the substring 34772 exists in qdebug, from within my test function?

```
********* Start testing of tst_NetSocket *********
Config: Using QTest library 4.8.6, Qt 4.8.6
PASS   : tst_NetSocket::initTestCase()
QDEBUG : tst_NetSocket::testBindToPortDefaultToMinAvailable() Bound to UDP port  34772 
FAIL!  : tst_NetSocket::testBindToPortDefaultToMinAvailable() 'socket->getCurrentPort() == port_should_be' returned FALSE. ()
   Loc: [test_net_socket.cpp(59)]
PASS   : tst_NetSocket::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 5 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
********* Finished testing of tst_NetSocket *********
```

Here's my test file. I want to add a `QVERIFY()` statement in my test function that checks the output of qDebug for the substring 34772.

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QtTest/QtTest>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "net_socket.hpp"

class tst_NetSocket: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    // ....
    void testBindToPortDefaultToMinAvailable();
};

// ... other tests removed for example ...

void tst_NetSocket::testBindToPortDefaultToMinAvailable()
{
    NetSocket * socket = new NetSocket();

    int port_should_be = (32768 + (getuid() % 4096)*4);
    if (socket->bindToPort()) {
        QVERIFY(socket->getCurrentPort() == port_should_be);
    }
}

QTEST_MAIN(tst_NetSocket)
#include "test_net_socket.moc"
```

Comment: Check out `qInstallMessageHandler`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [QTest::ignoreMessage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtest.html#ignoreMessage) to assert that a certain message is added in the code under test:

```
// ...
int port_should_be = (32768 + (getuid() % 4096)*4);
QTest::ignoreMessage(QtDebugMsg, QString::fromLatin1("Bound to UDP port  %1").arg(port_should_be).toUtf8().constData());
// ...
```